# Create ASP.Net-like user control in iOS framework

Tags: asp.net, objective-c, ios, interface-builder, user-controls

What I'm trying to do is something that I know is straight-forward in ASP.Net, and maybe I just need to adjust my thinking (I'm teaching myself development in iOS), but I cannot figure out how to accomplish this best with XCode/Objective-C.

What I want to do is layout several buttons, a label, and write some code in a reusable format like a user control in ASP.Net.  Then take that 'package' and use it in multiple places in a view on a storyboard.

I've seen a lot of examples for subclassing a single control, but what I want to do is package several controls together and then be able to drag/add that to the storyboard.  Is that feasible? Or do I need to create the class file but manually add all the controls to link them to the class?  Or is it better/possible to dynamically add the controls in the view/storyboard using the custom class?

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to design in IB you need to do a little more leg work.

To start we need something to contain our controls and to act as a controller so we need a subclass of `NSObject` and call it something sensible. (Better than MyWidget)

```
@interface MyWidget : UIView
```

for our basic starting canvas to lay our components on we will need a `UIView` that IB can get a handle to and use. Add this to your header

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *view;
```

Then give this ivar a getter/setter and do the memory management in the .m

```
@synthesize view = _view;

...

- (void)dealloc;
{
    [_view release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Now create a nib with a single view to start and set the `File's Owner` to `MyWidget`. You should now be able to `ctrl` + `click` and drag from the `File's Owner` to the `UIView` object and select `view`. So at this point our nib knows how to connect to our `MyWidget` class but our `MyWidget` class doesn't know about the nib.

In `MyWidget.m` we need to tell the class to use the nib in both `- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame;` and `- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder;` so we can instantiate the class in code or using IB.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self loadView];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder;
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self loadView];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)loadView;
{
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyView" owner:self options:nil];
    [self addSubview:self.view];
}
```

Now when out class is instantiated it will hook itself up to the nib. At this point you are back to how you normally work with a standard `UIViewController` e.g. add something to the xib then hook it up to your controller and use it.

In all a good starting point would look like ...

**MyWidget.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyWidget : UIView

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *view;

@end
```

**MyWidget.m**

```
#import "MyWidget.h"

@interface MyWidget ()

- (void)loadView;

@end

@implementation MyWidget

@synthesize view = _view;

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_view release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self loadView];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder;
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self loadView];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)loadView;
{
    // MyWidget is the name of the xib as well
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyWidget" owner:self options:nil];
    [self addSubview:self.view];
}

@end
```